# kstat in Solaris 11+

Tags: kernel, solaris, netstat

I'm writing a kernel-level program in Solaris that monitors the workload of the system and reports the stats --something similar to **netstats** in linux and **kstat** in Solaris. Where the source code for **kstat** is located in Solaris 11+ * source code?

*Edit: 12 -> 11

Comment: Solaris is proprietary now, so you can't get its source code. But it sounds like an XY problem, why you can't use Solaris 11 as the reference platform?

Comment: Did you mean Solaris 11? I don't think 12 has been announced. I'm pretty sure Oracle doesn't supply source code, either. Maybe through OTN?

Comment: What those guys said. Perhaps the illumos source will help you: https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/tree/master/usr/src/lib/libkstat

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean Solaris 11.2 as Solaris 12 is not yet released, possibly next year (2016) according to a [roadmap](https://blogs.oracle.com/gman/entry/oracle_solaris_12_and_ibm).

`/usr/bin/kstat` is a Perl script in Solaris 11.2 so while still proprietary code, you can certainly read its source code.

An alternative, C based open source version of the `kstat` command is available here  https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/tree/09f79f7c66b85f056db11f58210dc6182c9b1aef/usr/src/cmd/stat/kstat

It likely compiles and works fine with current and possibly future Solaris releases.

Comment: `kstat` is actually a kernel interface for providing various statistics. See [kstat_lookup(3KSTAT)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/817-0679/6mgfb87ap/index.html) for example. `/usr/bin/kstat` is one of the possible interfaces.

Comment: @myaut  I doubt the OP wants to rewrite an alternative to the low level kstat API. I then assume he is looking to the code of the kstat command. The fact he mentioned netstat, which is also based on the kstat library on Solaris but on the proc pseudo file system on Linux reinforced that impression.

Comment: @jilliagre: depends on language he uses. If you write it in C or C++, using native `libkstat` is definitely better than calling `perl`program and parsing its output.

Comment: @myaut can you please provide an example of using *libkstat* in C as an answer to this question. Thank!

Comment: @AliAbbasinasab A link to an open source C kstat implementation is already in my answer.

Comment: @myaut Absolutely. I have written such programs and the source code of mpstat, netstat, iostat and similar commands is available under the https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/tree/09f79f7c66b85f056db11f58210dc6182c9b1aef/usr/src/cmd/stat directory, along with the already mentioned kstat command.